# How to -enable- vim's "Press ENTER or type command to continue"

Tags: vim

There are lots of questions on here about how to disable the "Press ENTER or type command to continue" text when running an external command from vim. But I want to know how to **enable** it. As you can see below, I'm not using `silent` or any other means to disable it.

Here is the relevant portion of my .vimrc:

```
nmap <leader>r :call NoFrills()<CR>     "(r)eveal hidden chars
nmap <leader>i :set paste!<CR>          "(i)ndenting on/off
nmap <leader>h :set nohlsearch!<CR>     "(h)ighlighting of search terms on/off
nmap <leader>w :call SudoWrite()<CR>    "(w)rite file, sudoing first
nmap <leader>a :! sudo service httpd restart<CR>"(a)pache restart
nmap <leader>p :! perl -c %<CR>         "(p)erl -c
```

When I execute a command that should have output, like with the key sequence `\ p`, the command executes but any output is quickly dismissed from the screen without pausing or prompting me to continue. Why is that?

If I execute `:! perl -c %` from vim's command mode, it shows me the output and prompts me to continue, as expected.

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Feb 17 2012 10:23:31)

:set
--- Options ---
  background=dark     filetype=perl       incsearch           scrolloff=3         ttyfast
  comments=:#         helplang=en         list                shiftwidth=4        ttymouse=xterm
  commentstring=#%s   history=50          number              syntax=perl         viminfo='20,"50
  define=[^A-Za-z_]   hlsearch            ruler               tabstop=4           wildmenu
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  complete=.,w,b,u,t,i,k
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
  formatoptions=tcrq
  guicursor=n-v-c:block,o:hor50,i-ci:hor15,r-cr:hor30,sm:block,a:blinkon0
  include=\<\(use\|require\)\>
  includeexpr=substitute(substitute(v:fname,'::','/','g'),'$','.pm','')
  indentexpr=GetPerlIndent()
  indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e,0=,0),0=or,0=and
  isfname=@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~,=,:
  keywordprg=perldoc -f
  listchars=tab:>-,trail:o
  path=/usr/local/lib64/perl5,/usr/local/share/perl5,/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl,/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl,/usr/lib64/perl
5,/usr/share/perl5,,
  wildmode=longest,list,full
```

Comment: I don't know if they are actually in your vimrc or not but inline comments are forbidden for mappings.

Comment: you hit the nail on the head. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @romainl has already indicated in the comments, the appended comments are part of the mappings, and one of those characters (e.g. the `<Space>`) dismisses the hit-enter prompt. You *could* include a trailing comment by separating with `|` (which must be escaped or written as `<Bar>`) inside a mapping):

```
nnoremap <leader>p :! perl -c %<CR>| "(p)erl -c
```

But I'd recommend to put the comments on a separate line:

```
" (p)erl -c
nnoremap <leader>p :! perl -c %<CR>
```

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: I feel like a dummy now. I even have syntax highlighting on and didn't think twice when the comments were not highlighted as such. Thanks! (p.s. I've updated to nnoremap)